# PHP - Converting a String float to an Integer - Wrong value

Tags: php, rounding-error

Why does this code provide 853 instead of 854?

```
(int) ((float) ( "8.54") * 100);
```

How do I convert **(string)** `"8.54"` into **(integer)** `854`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/157957)

8.54 happens to be one of those numbers which can be written precisely in decimal, but not in binary, so `(float)"8.54"` will actually create a number *very very close to, but slightly under, 8.54*.

Multiplying that by 100 will create a number *very very close to, but slightly under, 854*. And casting to `int` will find the *next smallest* integer (e.g. 853.9 becomes 853, not 854).

I can think of two solutions:

- After multiplying by 100, round to the nearest whole number, then convert to integer. Unlike 8.54, 854 itself can be represented precisely in floating point, so `round(8.54 * 100)` will give a number that is *exactly* 854, rather than *slightly under* it. So `(int)round((float)"8.54" * 100)` will give 854 as an integer.
- Instead of multiplying by 100, remove the `.` from the string, and convert to int directly, e.g. `(int)str_replace(".", "", "8.54"));`

Comment: Rounding the number before casting to int seems to work. `(int)round((float) ( "8.54") * 100);`

Comment: @aynber Yep, I was just adding that suggestion :)

Comment: Yep! Thank you, just figured this out myself after scratching my head for over an hour!

Comment: IEEE 754 double precision format

Comment: `(int) round(((float) ( "8.54") * 100),0)` - this resolved this issue! I will mark the answer accepted once the time limit lifts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

intval(str_replace(".", "", "8.54"))

Comment: I did think this, but it just didn't feel right for some reason :-) Knew there was a mathematical approach to it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try without (int).
Like this => (float) ( "8.54") * 100;
In this case (int) not necessary.

Comment: That makes `854.0` though, not `854`.